# How show custom fields after product loop on shop page Woocommerce storefront?

Tags: woocommerce, storefront

I created an ACF for the shop page
[ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTVHG.jpg)
how do i show it after the products loop?
[SHOP PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0z9J.jpg)

I tried to use this code, but no work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); function woocommerce_after_shop_loop() {
if ( is_product_category() ) {
    echo esc_html__("Custom content", "amc");
 }
}
```